# In React how to refresh page and open new modal after refresh page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good day! I have one modal where is u can pick modal #1 and #2. 
And if u go to modal #2 there is need to open in modal #1(but this is one modal with `(if department.id == 1 ? test : test2)` and how i can open modal #2 in modal #1 when isvisible is one for this two modal? or can i refresh page and directly open modal #1 auto after we put the button?

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return ( < button onClick = {this._refreshPage} > test </button>);
      }

      _refreshPage() {
        console.log("Clicked");
        window.location.reload();
      }
    }


ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Can you please share some sample code, possible check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: how to refresh page with state update for (refreshed page?)

Comment: If you modify the state, the component automatically re-renders.

Comment: @Alexiostigrahauda your question is not suitable to understand. what do you mean by   "if u go to modal #2 there is need to open in modal #1" ? how you handle open/close model ? if you provide useful info someone can help you.